# Netty getting PrematureChannelClosureException

Tags: prometheus, netty

Netty with recent [Fix](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/13290) in version 4.1.91, made this issue of getting `PrematureChannelClosureException` using with prometheus `remote_write` for metrics.
When i debugged the code , i could see [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/netty-4.1.91.Final/codec/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/compression/SnappyFrameDecoder.java#L139) its throwing an Exception. The same thing was working fine with 4.1.90 & below versions.
And now I get some bits and pieces, that its due to inactive channel that cause this Exception.In this another issue also mentioned [Here](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/13252) its mentioning about illegal content in `HttpObjectAggregator` http response. What that means?
Could anyone has any idea?